# Should I wait to complete three years before I leave?

Tags: quitting

My current role is a cushy one but I don't think staying in for five years is healthy because it would cause prolonged senility. All the colleagues surrounded me were kind but they all showed symptoms of lethargy. None has ever not complained that they stayed for too long. Additional "challenges" were just dirty workload that they do not want to get their hands on and that they just threw it to me.

By the end of November I would have been working in my present office for three years. All my previous employments were in a totally different industry but were all terrible as I hopped across too many organizations. My credentials weren't fantastic either, as I have only a general business degree and I am turning 30s this year. I am a single woman.

I firmly wish to work overseas but the chances of getting an overseas job is sky-high. I've attempted all methods internally but none were given. Should I bear for another five more months before I quit or should I just grab the next opportunity (local job) when it sets on my footstep?

Comment: what field is this?

Comment: I am in oil and gas industry.

Comment: How does working 5 more months improve your chances of getting a job overseas?

Comment: It gives me more time to get a new job?

Comment: Keep trying for the overseas job!  What did you do this week to search one - try harder!

Comment: Questions about what you *should* or *shouldn't* do with your career aren't really on topic around here.  Is there a specific question about your workplace that you wanted answered in all this?

Comment: @Anonymous123 Right, but why 5 months specifically? Why not 3 months or 6 months? What is the significance of 3 years?

Comment: @Masked Man Wouldn't it look better on a resume for a person with three years of experience than 2.5yrs?

Comment: @Steve-O Yes my question simply is, when is it the best time I should leave the company?

Comment: @Anonymous123 If you are concerned about being seen as a "job hopper", my personal threshold is 2 years, any number of days you stick around beyond that makes no difference.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it makes a difference. The reason people advocate staying for at least 1 year with an employer is that "job hopping" (frequent stints of a couple of months) may raise red flags for prospective employers.

Since you've already held your job for 2+ years, there's no reason to stay there "just because". (Unless there's some company-specific reason like getting a bonus or something.)

Keep searching for a new job and don't quit until you got accepted (or things get really bad). If your current employment for some reason makes it more likely (same industry etc.) to find your dream job overseas, you may want to stay there until you either find that dream job or a job that's likely to increase these chances. If you've done a lot of job hopping before, take care not to fall back into old habits.